# ntdll!RtlpMuiRegFreeRegistryInfo() and SIGSEGV while using pointer

Tags: c++

I've got an error in my code when I use pointer. Everything is OK when I create two objects and then use method like this:

```
Insect* insect;
Leaf leaf;
leaf.affect(insect);
```

(So far affect method does nothing but print some text)
But when I change it into:

```
Insect* insect;
Leaf* leaf;
leaf->affect(insect);
```

I've got SIGSEGV and `ntdll!RtlpMuiRegFreeRegistryInfo()` in debugger. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Leaf leaf;
```

Creates a `Leaf` that exist as an automatic object.  You can then call member functions on it as you have a valid object.

```
Leaf* leaf;
```

Creates a pointer to a `Leaf` and it points to some garbage location.  When you try to use that garbage pointer you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and in this case a SIGSEGV.

In order for the second case to work you need to allocate memory for it like

```
Leaf* leaf = new Leaf;
```

Don't forget that if you use `new`/`new[]` then you need to call `delete`/`delete[]` when you are done with the pointer to return the memory.

Comment: Daaamn that's obvious I don't know why I forgot about it. Thank you :)

Comment: @user5514633 No problem.